# Before the discovery of India, was it self sufficient in all areas?

Tags: india, ancient-india

As per the history books, India was discovered from Europe by Vasco da Gama. I just want to know was India self sufficient in all the areas like food, military, medicine and other materials, stuff required in day-today life before it had access to European trade?

How was the Indian economy that time?

Comment: India wasn't discovered by Vasco da Gama. He was the first European to find a sea route from Europe to India. Also, what has this to do with the UK? (**mod note:** Answers in chat please. Any posted here may be summarily deleted).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63924/discussion-on-question-by-sparrowtrajon-before-the-discovery-of-india-was-it-se).

Answer (score 4):

Vasco da Gama did *not* discover India. He merely was the first European to sail there without going through the Ottoman Empire.

India was on the [Silk Road](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/74/Silk_route.jpg). I've no idea if it was self-sufficient, but at the very least it was well connected to the Old World's trade network and [prosperous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_history_of_India#Mughal_Empire) at the time.

[image: Silk Roads]

Answer (score 4):

[**Classical to early medieval periods (c. 200 BCE–1200 CE)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_India)

> During this period, India's economy is estimated to have been the largest in the world, having between one-third and one-quarter of the world's wealth, from 1 CE to 1000 CE.

Also this [article](http://cgijeddah.mkcl.org/WebFiles/History-of-Indian-Economy.pdf) describes that Indian economy was very good in 1000AD

So this means that India was self sufficient in all areas you have mentioned above, then only the Indian economy was good.

Comment: I am pretty sure that Roman Empire was economically bigger than India till about 300 or 400 AD

Comment: Greg, I will be glad if you provide me some information about this. Thanks!